# How can I hide endpoint url in angular js and nginx server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx

1. Hi , I want to hide the endpoint url in angular js . I have deployed
   the app on nginx. current :  url:  'http://localhost:8080/' +
   action, expected: /action

   I dont want to expose the http call endpoint ip .

   Please help!

   ```
   mediaApp.service('Services', function($http, $q) {
       return {
           serviceCall: function(action, dataObj, authorization, method) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               var response = {};
               var promise = $http({
                       url:  'http://localhost:8080/' + action,
                       method: method,
                       data: dataObj,
                       headers: {
                           'Authorization': authorization
                       }
                   })
                   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               })
               .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                   return {
                       "status": false
                   };
               });
           return promise;
       }
   }; });
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Your angular code shouldn't refer to a url with localhost in it, because as soon as you deploy that on the web it will fail

Comment: Mikkel: localhost is just an example  . Actual endpoint is different.

Comment: If you are doing a http call from the browser, you can't hide it. Even if you obfuscate the code, they will be able to see the URL in the network tab. The only way is to send a http request to your server, and have that make another http request to the real destination. That approach, despite being more work, is good because it means you can avoid any CORS problems

Comment: Can I add my http url in nginx as a variable and then refer the endpoint from js?

Comment: You can create an environment variable in nginx, or you can make it a variable for your server code. The endpoint is whatever you would like it to be